# Can not validate iOS archive for distribution on test flight

Tags: ios, apple-developer, apple-developer-account

I am trying to prepare an iOS app for distribution on test flight (and eventually on the app store).

The Apple developer account admin has sent me the .cer file and the .p12 private key (which they just created). I have added both to my keychain.

Inside of xcode organizer, I select the app and hit validate. I then subsequently select "Automatically manage signing" and hit next.

I am then presented with 4 errors.

> This request is forbidden for security reasons. You do not currently
> have access to the membership resource.

> No signing certificate iOS distribution found. No "iOS distribution"
> signing certificate with ID blah with a private key was found.

> Team "my team" does not have permission to create iOS app store
> provision profiles. Select a different team and try again.

> No profiles for [my bundle id] were found. XCode couldn't find any iOS
> app store provision profiles matching [my bundle id]

I was under the impression (from what I have read) that having both the distribution cert and the private key in my keychain would be sufficient to distribute the app.

Comment: FYI the private key and the certificate names do not match in my keychain. Not sure if that matters.

Comment: Has the administrator added your Apple ID to the team and given you the appropriate access? - You will need "developer" if the app has already been created in App Store Connect or "App Admin" if not.

Comment: My role is App Manager.